# Detecting flash clicks through jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, flash

I only have very limited control over a flash application. The only thing I can do is modify some links in an XML that it reads from.

I want to execute JS code based on the selected item in flash. I can link to something like: currentpage.html#some_anchor, but is there any way for me to detect the URL change from jQuery?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As alopix mentioned, you can use the HTML5 event, *onhashchange*, for IE8+, Chrome 5+ and Firefox 3.6+.

Since you're already using jQuery, you might want to take a look at [this plugin](http://benalman.com/projects/jquery-hashchange-plugin/) by Ben Alman, which makes an implementation of the event available for unsupporting browsers.  This makes it as simple as:

```
$(window).hashchange(function () {
    alert(window.location.hash);
});
```

You can also use [*ExternalInterface.call()*](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flash/articles/external_interface_05.html) to invoke a JavaScript function from Flash, which is probably a lot simpler for what you need, but doesn't help much if you don't have access to the Flash code.

Answer (score 1):

In modern browsers you can listen to the onhashchange-event.

```
$(function() {
    $(window).bind('hashchange', function() {
        // more here
    });
});
```

In IE<8 you have to set an interval and poll if the hash has changed.

```
var i = window.setInterval('checkforhashchange', 500);
```